# Visual Studio Emulator for Android - Project does not Deploy

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

Windows 8.1

Visual Studio 2015 RC

Android Application API Level 21 (Xamarin.Android v5.0 Support)

I recently had to rebuild a new PC as my old one had major problems. On this new PC, the project compiles and the emulator launches. However, during the emulator OS load screen I receive a message stating:

"This pre-release version of the Visual Studio Emulator for Android will expire in 3 day(s), 13 hour(s). Please upgrade to a newer version."

After I click "OK" the emulator OS finishes loading and I receive the message "2>Emulator launched successfully." in the Visual Studio Output window.

On my previous PC I did not receive the pop during the emulator's load and after the emulator finished loading it would then deploy the application to the emulator and begin debugging. However, after the emulator finishes loading on my new PC, no further output is displayed in Visual Studio and the green load bar in the bottom right corner of Visual Studio sits at about 30%.

I have been unable to find any information online related to the popup message I receive during the emulators load screen. I cannot find any update for the emulator or Visual Studio. I have uninstalled and re-installed Android Studio, Xamarin Studio, and Visual Studio twice with no change.

How do I update to the latest version?

Why would Visual Studio not deploy the project when the debugger begins?

Comment: Hey Paul--we're rolling out an update today. You should get a toast in the VS Notification hub asking you to update the emulator. Installing the update will fix the expiry issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that I had to launch Visual Studio with elevated permissions. I changed the properties for the shortcut and checked the field "Run as Administrator" and all is well again.

Comment: I'm launching VS 2015 with elevated permissions to "Run as Administrator", too.  However, I still get the "pre-release" message when I run the Android emulator.

Comment: @ChrisSwain we're rolling out an update today. You should get a toast in the VS Notification hub asking you to update the emulator. Installing the update will fix the expiry issue.

Comment: @JohnKemnetz - I got the updated emulator.  Now I get this message alert:  "The emulator is unable to connect to the device operating system: The device did not respond to the connect request. Some functionality might be disabled."  This alert message is shown after the emulator launches when I try to run my Xamarin.Android project. The emulator launches and says "OS is starting..." for a long time, then the message alert is shown.

Comment: @JohnKemnetz - Update: Rebooted after installing the new emulator and now it works great!

Comment: @JohnKemnetz Thank you so much. This resolved the last annoyance of my problem. I had to reboot after update as well in order to launch emulator.

Answer (score 7):

I had the some problem, and I was able to fix it by manually running `adb connect emulatorhost:5555` from the command line.

Comment: This method works for me! You can go to the emulator, click the ">>" arrow at the bottom of the right sidebar, go to "Network" to see the address for the Emulator Adapter. Take it and run `adb connect IP_address`. Port `5555` is the default so it's optional.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same Problem, elevated permissions not works. Run adb from commandline is alreay connected.

The new update from Xamiran (version 4.0.4.4), fix this problem for me. :)